# ExpressJS - PassportJS LocalStrategy: Get current logged in user

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I have an expressjs server where I'm using the Passport Local strategy.
But something isn't working probably

My Login Route in login.js File

```
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/v2/api/',
    failureRedirect: '/v2/api/loginfailed',
    failureFlash: true
}), async (req, res, next) => {
});
```

And I want to get the information about the current logged in user in another route (dashboard.js)

```
router.post('/dashboard', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        if (req.user) {
            res.json({ user: req.user })
        } else {
            res.status(403).send({
                message: 'Not authenticated failed'
            });
        }
    } catch {
        res.status(400).send({
            message: 'Request failed'
        });
        throw new Error('Error')
    }
});
```

On Execution: If I'm logging in via /login and calling the /dashboard Route, it response me only :

```
{
"user": {}
}
```

Did I missed out something or is it just not even possible what I want to do?

Thanks for your Answers :)

Comment: Are you serializing and deserializing the user  like stated in the docs?

Comment: I'm de-/serializing like that: `passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
        console.log("User with id " + user.userid + " is serialized");
        done(null, user.userid);
    });
    passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
        return done(null, getUserByID(id));
    }); `